# Multiple onPreferenceChangeListeners in 1 Activity

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, preferences

How can I use multiple onPrefernceChangeListeners in a SettingsFragment Activity? I already have the following code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;


public class SettingsFragment extends 
PreferenceFragmentCompat implements
    Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    Preference currency_list = findPreference("currency_list");
    currency_list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    Preference switch_box_show_idle_dialog = findPreference("switch_show_idle_dialog");
    switch_box_show_idle_dialog.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference currency_list, Object newValue){
    String currency_list_Key = currency_list.getKey();
    boolean currency_list_Value = (boolean) newValue;

    if(currency_list_Key.equals("currency_list")){
        //onChangeListener here
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference switch_show_idle_dialog, Object newValue) {
    String switch_preferenceKey = switch_show_idle_dialog.getKey();
    boolean switch_show_idle_dialog_Value = (boolean) newValue;

    if(switch_preferenceKey.equals("switch_show_idle_dialog")){
        //onChangeListener here
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Android Studio marks the

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference switch_show_idle_dialog, Object newValue)
```

part red on both listeners. Is it possible to have both listeners active? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** override a method twice in the same class, when a preference changed, the `onPreferenceChange()` method will call, now you can use the `Preference` parameter in this method to check which preference changed, so you can do like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

    if (preference.getKey().equals("switch_show_idle_dialog")) {

        //your code

        return true;
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("currency_list")) {

        //your code

        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```